# Emphasis using comma

Tags: grammar, adjectives, commas, emphasis, compound-sentences

Are these sentences correct?

- And he called me, a liar.
- And he called you, a doofus.
- And he called you, dumb.

These are sort of like used as sarcasm or irony. I don't know but these feel right in my head for the emphasis on the adjectives.

Comment: Very much no. Don’t do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comma can change the meaning (including the verb), perhaps as

> And he called me, a liar.
> That liar called me.

> And he called you, a doofus.
> And he called a dofus like you.

> And he called you, dumb.
> It was dumb of him to call you.

The meaning and the emphasis would be clearer in quotation marks.

> And he called you "dumb".

Comment: Yeah that makes sense, Thank you.